# Finding ++ in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find ++ or -- or // or ** sign in in string can anyone help me?

```
var str = document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML;
var res = str.substring(0, str.length);
var patt1 = ++,--,//,**;
var result = str.match(patt1);  
if (result)
{
    alert("you cant do this :l");
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML='';
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions, like strings, must be enclosed in delimiters `/`.

Comment: i know this but when i type var patt1 = /[++]/i; code find + and ++ too

Comment: And special characters, like `+`, have to be escaped. Besides that, why use a regular expression at all? `if (str.indexOf("++") > -1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your pattern like this:

```
var patt1 = /\+\+|--|\/\/|\*\*/;
```

Now it should do what you want.

More info about regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 6):

This finds doubles of the characters by a backreference:

```
/([+\/*-])\1/g
```

> [from q. comments]: i know this but when i type var patt1 = /[++]/i; code find + and ++

`[++]` means one arbitrary of the characters. Normally `+` is the qantifier "1 or more" and needs to be escaped by a leading backslash when it should be a literal, except in brackets where it does not have any special meaning.

Characters that do need to be escaped in character classes are e.g. the escape character itself (backslash), the expression delimimiter (slash), the closing bracket and the range operator (dash/minus), the latter except at the end of the character class as in my code example.

A character class `[]` matches one character. A quantifier, e.g. `[abc]{2}` would match "aa", "bb", but "ab" as well.

You can use a backreference to a match in parentheses:

`/(abc)\1`

Here the `\1` refers to the first parentheses `(abc)`. The entire expression would match "abcabc".

To clarify again: We could use a quantifier on the backreference:

```
/([+\/*-])\1{9}/g
```

This matches exactly 10 *equal* characters out of the class, the subpattern itself and 9 backreferences more.

`/.../g` finds all occurrences due to the modifier global (g).

[test-case on regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=106285)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`/\+\+|--|\/\/|\*\*/`

as your expression.

Here I have escaped the special characters by using a backslash before each (`\`).

I've also used `.test(str)` on the regular expression as all you need is a boolean (`true`/`false`) result.

See working example below:

```js
var str = document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML;
var res = str.substring(0, str.length);

var patt1 = /\+\+|--|\/\/|\*\*/;
var result = patt1.test(res);

if (result) {
  alert("you cant do this :l");
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  This is some++ text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

As

1. `n+`:-   Matches any string that contains at least one n
2. `n*` Matches any string that contains zero or more occurrences of n

We need to use backslash before this special characters.

```js
 var str = document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML;
    var res = str.substring(0, str.length);
    var patt1 = /\+\+|--|\/\/|\*\*/;
    var result = str.match(patt1);  
    if (result)
        {
        alert("you cant do this :l");
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML='';
        }
```

```html
<div id="screen">2121++</div>
```